# Yodlee REST API - Cobrand Context Expiration

Tags: yodlee

Does the Cobrand Context (ie it's session token) ever expire? If yes, how long is it valid for before it expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,

CobrandContext expires in 120mins. As a best practice Yodlee suggests to renew it every 90mins or so.

Regards,
Prashant

Comment: Hi Prashant,

How can we renew the token generated from Yodlee ? Do we need to call the service again which generate the token ?